# android categorized listview with custom header

Tags: android, listview

I already have a sectional listview that works with a general string as the header per section. Now I would like to extend this to also put a image in the header as well. Here is how the adapter is that works well. I have a custom layout as well.

What do I need to adjust in the section header to be able to include the image along with the string in the header? I've already tried a few things, inflate view and set items in addSection, but they all resulted in errors so I'm back to the beginning.

Here is the adapter

```
public final Map<String, Adapter> sections = new LinkedHashMap<>();
public final ArrayAdapter<String> headers;
public final static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;

public SectionalListAdapter(Context context)
{
    headers = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.list_header);
}
public void addSection(String section, Drawable icon, Adapter adapter)
{
    this.headers.add(section);
    this.sections.put(section, adapter);
}
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0) return section;
        if (position < size) return adapter.getItem(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
    }
    return null;
}
public int getCount()
{
    // total together all sections, plus one for each section header
    int total = 0;
    for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getCount() + 1;
    return total;
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    // assume that headers count as one, then total all sections
    int total = 1;
    for (Adapter adapter : this.sections.values())
        total += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    return total;
}
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    int type = 1;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0) return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
        if (position < size) return type + adapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        type += adapter.getViewTypeCount();
    }
    return -1;
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for (Object section : this.sections.keySet())
    {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section
        if (position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
        if (position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        sectionnum++;
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position){return position;}
```